# Flutter InteractiveViewer class how to Zoom/scale out when loading a new Image

Tags: image, flutter, zooming

I love the [InteractiveViewer class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InteractiveViewer-class.html), it allows me the user to pinch out to zoom in on Image Widgets.

However, it's given me a bug.  If the user remains zoomed in on an image, then exits my DetailsScreen containing that image, then activates DetailScreen again with new details and image, then the new image is zoomed in by the same amount as the old one.  The InteractiveViewer's scale is not being reset.

I've tried to reset it by giving the InteractiveViewer a `transformationController: imageZoomController,` parameter in its constructor.  Then when I exit the DetailScreen I tried `imageZoomController.dispose()`, however this causes lots of crashes... hmmmph.

It just needs to reset to being fully zoomed out, I need to retrigger InteractiveViewer's initial `minScale: 1,`  parameter.

I don't favour using InteractiveViewer's `onInteractionEnd` parameter, because I find it annoying when I've intentionally zoomed in on an image and it jumps away from it.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Hi There. Post some widget codes, so that we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution through experimentation, it appears to work in the emulator, not quite sure why, but problem solved I hope.

```
imageZoomController.value = Matrix4.identity();
Navigator.of(context).pop();
```

When I exit the DetailsScreen twiddling the imageZoomController.value seems to reset the InteractiveViewer to a zoom of 1.

Thanks for the suggestion Thea, if others have my problem & my solution doesn't work, then try Thea's plugin.

I'll provide more context, Widgets etc. in future, my bad.  Apologies @Nisanth

Answer (score 3):

You can try this package: https://pub.dev/packages/photo_view

It also allows us to double click to animate to init scale without even touch the controller.

Usage:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    child: PhotoView(
      imageProvider: AssetImage("assets/large-image.jpg"),
    )
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, check if the image or widget is already zoomed in then take it to default zoom.

```
            final _transformationController = TransformationController();
            if (_transformationController.value != Matrix4.identity()) {
                  _transformationController.value = Matrix4.identity();
                }

Widget:
        InteractiveViewer(
              transformationController: _transformationController,
              child:Container(),
             ),
```

Answer (score 0):

**viewController.value = Matrix4.identity();**

GET YOU TO THE INITIAL ZOOM OF THE PHOTO

```
TransformationController viewController = TransformationController();

    var initialControllerValue;
    
    InteractiveViewer(
     
        transformationController: viewController,
        onInteractionStart: (details){

            initialControllerValue = viewController.value;
        },
    
        onInteractionEnd: (details){
   
            viewController.value = initialControllerValue;
        },
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).